# python plotly fig.write_image() is no response

Tags: python, image, plotly

I want to save the plot drawn through the plotly as a 'png' file.
I wrote the code with my laptop, and the png file was saved well in the laptop. But when the code was operated on another computer, 'fig.write_image() part', there is a phenomenon of infinite looping.

No errors or messages come out, and no matter how long I wait, 'fig.write_image()' code does not proceed any more and the png file is not generated. What is the cause of this problem?
Pip install-Ukaleido is installed as requested by plotly.

There is no error in fig.show() or other code.

Comment: Can you include the code you used that leads to this problem?

Comment: fig.wirte_image('filename.png') the other code no problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.